# Mockito Java Test Always Passes - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, xml, testing, junit, mockito

This is the code I want to test. The code runs fine, as I have the dependency.xml in resources (where it should be). It executes correctly.

```
@Component
public class ProjectBuilderBean {

public List<String> getDependencyList() {
    List<String> listDeps = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File xmlFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("dependency.xml").getFile());
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("dependency");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                String dependency = eElement.getElementsByTagName("artifactId").item(0).getTextContent();
                listDeps.add(dependency);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listDeps;
    }
}
```

This is the test I've written and for some reason it always passes. I do not understand why and how it passes, but I know for a fact that it should not. I've added nothing to the list and it somehow still passes, even when I add it passes. Here is the test:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ProjectBuilderBeanTest {

@Mock
private ProjectBuilderController projectBuilderBeanMock;

//Decleration of the Class Instance
@Mock
ProjectBuilderBean projectBuilderBean;

/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    //Initialise the mocking of the class
    projectBuilderBean = Mockito.mock(ProjectBuilderBean.class);
}

@Test
public void getDependencyListTest() throws Exception {

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    result.add("a");
    result.add("b");
    when(projectBuilderBean.getDependencyList()).thenReturn(result);

}

/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    projectBuilderBean = null;
    }
}
```

Simply trying to test the consistency of the list generated through the dependency.xml file.

Here is a screenshot of the depenedency.xml: http://screenshot.net/3qoe4s0

Comment: I'm not sure that your test method is actually testing anything.It just tells the mocked object what it will have to return on the method call .

Comment: Also, your code is NOT fine. As soon as it will be packaged in a jar file, it won't work anymore. A resource loaded by the ClassLoader is NOT a file. Pass a uri or an InputStream to parse(), not a File.

Comment: Could you point me in a direction that could at least get me started please @Berger?

Comment: @Vivek Patani , you should use some of the `assert` methods like `assertTrue` or `assertEquals` , etc.. these will test your code.However, mocking `ProjectBuilderBean` has no use, you want to test it, so test the real thing (pass a test xml file to it, and assert that the result of its parsing are the expected result, for instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to echo the commenter, but the reason your "test" is always passing is because you're not testing anything.  You're "exercising" your code.  You're not asserting any side effects, you're not verifying any mock calls.